# Android facebook-sdk crash in Turkish

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-4.0, illegalargumentexception

When I selected `Turkish language`, I get an error.
No problem in other language, if i delete facebook-sdk fix it. But I have to use facebook-sdk..

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CLİCK is not a constant in com.facebook.appevents.codeless.internal.EventBinding$ActionType

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
mavenCentral()}

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

and **Manifest**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

NOTE : İ letter returns from facebook and it has been created by runtime. I did not write any İ letter. Please do not reply as write İ letter as lower case. I already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.
Workaround is use version 4.33.0 and lower.

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

**UPDATE (12.06.20)** 
There is no crash in the latest Facebook SDK (5.15.3)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about the facebook-sdk, but I see a dot on top of the uppercase letter I in the word CLİCK, and in a Turkish locale, `toUppercase("i")` doesn't return `"I"`, but `"İ"`. So I bet that somewhere a lowercase `"click"` is converted to `"CLİCK"` using `toUpperCase()` without specifying a sensible locale like e.g. `Locale.ROOT`.

As this is a very special "feature" of Turkish case conversions (and no other language, as far as I know), that would explain why this only happens in Turkish language.

Maybe someone with more knowledge on facebook-skd can point you to the place where the case conversion happens and how to repair it.

Comment: Do not share your little ideas if you do not have idea. CL"İ"CK keyword returns from facebook while runtime. My project does not have CL"İ"CK keyword. 

You are thing your self as big when you write a comment you wrote click bla bla bla. Keep your comment to your self. 

I can build project but that mean i havent used any CL"i"CK keyword. You just are waste of time nothing more

Comment: Do you know what is runtime ?